# How can I filter dates yearly with table functions?

Tags: c#, .net, database, datatable

I use finaquant's [table functions](http://finaquant.com/products/finaquantprotos) for filtering data tables after dates. The signature of a filter function (monthly) is as follows:

```
public static MatrixTable FilterDatesMonthly(MatrixTable Tbl, string DateField, int FirstDayOfRange, int LastDayOfRange, NumVector AllowMonthDays, NumVector AllowWeekDays)
```

There are two filtering functions, one monthly, one quarterly..

How can I filter dates on a yearly basis with table functions? Is there an easy way which I can't see?